# custom DDEV pull provider to update local database and user generated files

Tags: typo3, ddev

I'm trying to create a custom DDEV Provider, to import the current database and also user generated files from the web server.

I want to use it with TYPO3 Projects, where I develop the EXT locally with DDEV (because its awesome :) ) and I want to update my local database and also the "fileadmin" files with the help of the `ddev pull` function.

I've read the docs: [Introduction to Hosting Provider Integration](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/providers/provider-introduction/) and I tested the bash commands locally within the DDEV Container (`ddev ssh`) and I'm able to connect to the remote Webserver and make a database dump and transfer it to the local DDEV container.

So I added the bash commands to the my custom provider .yaml file in the /provider/ folder.

Here is the current file:

```
environment_variables:
  DB_NAME: db_name
  DB_USER: password
  DB_PASSWORD: password
  HOST_IP: 11.11.11.11
  SSH_USERNAME: username
  SSH_PASSWORD: password
  SSH_PORT: 22

db_pull_command:
  command: |
    # Creates the .download folder if it doesn't exist
    mkdir -p /var/www/html/.ddev/.downloads
    # execute the mysqldump on the remote webserver via SSH
    ssh -p ${SSH_PORT} ${SSH_USERNAME}@${HOST_IP} 'mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u ${DB_USER} -p ${DB_PASSWORD} ${DB_NAME} > /tmp/${DB_NAME}.sql.gz'
    # download to sql file to the ddev folder
    scp -P ${SSH_PORT} ${SSH_USERNAME}@${HOST_IP}:/tmp/${DB_NAME}.sql.gz /var/www/html/.ddev/.downloads/db.sql.gz.
```

If I execute the pull with `ddev pull my-provider` I get the following Error:

```
Downloading database...
bash: 03: command not found
Pull failed: Failed to exec mkdir -p /var/www/html/.ddev/.downloads
```

I assumed that the commands are executed like I would within the DDEV Container (with `ddev ssh`). What am I missing?

My Environment:

- TYPO3 v10.4.20
- Windows 10 (WSL)
- Docker Desktop 3.5.2
- DDEV-Local version v1.17.7
- architecture amd64
- db drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.3:v1.17.7
- dba phpmyadmin:5
- ddev-ssh-agent drud/ddev-ssh-agent:v1.17.0
- docker 20.10.7
- docker-compose 1.29.2

The web server is running on Plesk.

Note: I only tried to implement the db pull command so far.

---

UPDATE 09.11.21:

So I've gotten this far that I'm able update and also download the files. However I'm only able to do it, if I hardcode the variables. Everytime I'm trying to setup the `environment_variables:` I get the following error, if I run the `ddev pull myProvider`:

```
Downloading database...
bash: 03: command not found
```

Here is my current .yaml file with the `environment_variables:`, which currently don't work. I've tested all the commands within `ddev ssh`
and it works if I call them manually.

```
environment_variables:
  DB_NAME: db_name
  DB_USER: db_user
  DB_PASSWORD: 'Password$'
  HOST_IP: 10.10.10.10
  SSH_USERNAME: username
  SSH_PORT: 21

auth_command:
  command: |
    ssh-add -l >/dev/null || ( echo "Please 'ddev auth ssh' before running this command." && exit 1 )

db_pull_command:
  command: |
    mkdir -p /var/www/html/.ddev/.downloads
    ssh -p ${SSH_PORT} ${SSH_USERNAME}@${HOST_IP} "mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u ${DB_USER} -p'${DB_PASSWORD}' ${DB_NAME} > /tmp/${DB_NAME}.sql"
    scp -P ${SSH_PORT} ${SSH_USERNAME}@${HOST_IP}:/tmp/${DB_NAME}.sql /var/www/html/.ddev/.downloads/db.sql
    gzip -f /var/www/html/.ddev/.downloads/db.sql

files_pull_command:
  command: |
    scp -P ${SSH_PORT} -r ${SSH_USERNAME}@${HOST_IP}:/path/to/public/fileadmin/user_upload /var/www/html/.ddev/.downloads/files
```

Do I declare the variables the wrong way? Or what is it that I'm missing?

---

For anyone who has trouble connecting via ssh without the password promt, you can run the following commands:

1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2. `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -p 22 username@host`
3. Afterward you should be able to connect without a password promt. Try the following: `ssh -p 22 username@host`
4. before you try to `ddev puul` you have to execute `ddev auth ssh`

Comment: The best way to debug this is to `ddev ssh` and set the variables you have in the environment_variables section and then just execute the commands in the `db_pull_command` section one at a time.

My suspicion is that in `ssh -p ${SSH_PORT} ${SSH_USERNAME}@${HOST_IP} 'mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u ${DB_USER} -p ${DB_PASSWORD} ${DB_NAME} > /tmp/${DB_NAME}.sql.gz'` you single-quoted that whole section, so none of the variables get interpolated. And the redirection is inside the single quotes, so that wil probably not work out either?

Comment: I've updated my question with the my update. The current problem are the environment_variables which throw an error.

Comment: With what you show, DB_NAME will be set to `db_name`. Is that really what you're doing? I assume you're using real values there? See example in https://github.com/drud/ddev/blob/0a2bc2c7b830fdfde47067ac888ad4f82d8c4e2b/pkg/ddevapp/dotddev_assets/providers/platform.yaml.example#L23-L26

You need to say what you mean by "throw an error".

And please set the environment variables manually, and then run the steps in the db section one at a time manually in the web container.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn,t clear on that. The environment variables are dummy varaibles not my real ones. I've added a dummy Password with a special character since I thought that this might cause the error.
I've tested it manually in the web container, where I set the environment variables manually and the ran all commands after each other. 
And what other information do you need when it "throws an error"? The `ddev pull` will abort after the error message I've shown above.

Comment: As I said, the way to test is to `ddev ssh` and then manually set the environment variables. `export DB_NAME=db_name` etc. Then run the commands in the `auth_command` and the `db_pull_command` one at a time. See what happens. Have you done that? BTW, I don't think putting a `$` in a variable will likely work out as that's a special character in the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @rfay for pointing me into the right direction.

The Problem was, that my password containted a special charater (not a `$` though) which needed to be escaped.

After escpaing it correctly like so

```
environment_variables:
  DB_PASSWORD: 'Password\&\'
```

the `ddev pull` works.

I hope my .yaml file helps someone else that needs to pull from a webserver.